# Match string which is half inside tag and half ouside

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match string with value "vikas" which is half in some tag(any tag dont use span only) and half outside of it.

e.g:

```
<span class="can-map"><span id="1" class="can-map">vikas</span></span> 
<span id="2" class="can-map">vi<span>kas</span></span>
```

by using this regex:  /vikas/gi

I am getting value inside id=1 but not from id=2. Kindly help.

[regexr link](http://regexr.com/4n3ge)

Comment: using regexes to parse html is a futile enterprise, consider an html parser

Comment: If this is not HTML but some text (not that long) with HTML tags you may consider a regex approach, though it will not be efficient, hard to read and maintain. Something like `html.match(new RegExp(key.split("").map(function(x){return x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')}).join("(?:<[^<>]+>)*"), "gi")).length`.

Comment: Take the closest common ancestor, and retrieve `textContent` of it.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew can we add some class to match tags. if possible can you correct your method.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getVikas() { 
  const reg =  /vikas/gi;
    
    var one = document.getElementById('1');
    var two = document.getElementById('2');
    
    console.log(reg.test(two.innerText)); // true
    
}

getVikas();
```

```html
<span class="can-map"><span id="1" class="can-map">vikas</span></span> 
<span id="2" class="can-map">vi<span>kas</span></span>
```

Try something like this